# How do you type this in Chinese?

Tags: translation

I want to be able to type this in Chinese but I cannot recognize the characters.

[image: Text]

Comment: it is 中国往事  (China's past )

Answer (score 1):

if you are using pinyin then just type: zhong guo wang shi

Comment: Google translation - 钟国王石 (simplified); 鍾國王石 (traditional) :) Try this : "zhōng guó wǎng shì".

Answer (score 1):

"Pinyin" is quite efficient to find the Chinese word, which usually has many siblings with similar pronunciations. The siblings are listed as alternatives after the input pinyin. For this case:

[image]

Also, you need to specify the format of the result - simplified (mainly used in China, Macao) or traditional (mainly used in Taiwan, HK). For example, the pinin "guo" can be written as 国 (simplified), or 國 (traditional). For your case, it is the former/simplified Chinese.

Have fun!:)